# My regular expression code not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I had to rewrite this regular expression for Unicode (utf-8, cyrillic):

```
match: /\b(\w{2,})$/,
```

Using this regular expressions:

```
(/[\wа-я]+/ig)

(/[\w\u0430-\u044f]+/ig)
```

I rewrote this way:

```
match: /\b(\wа-яa-z{2,})+/ig$/
```

But my reg.exp code not working. Please help me.
Full code:

```
$('.form-control').textcomplete([
{ 
words: ["россия","сша","англия","германия","google","git","github","php","microsoft","jquery"], 

match: /(?:^|[^\wа-я])([\wа-я]{2,})$/i,

search: function (term, callback) 
{ 
    callback($.map(this.words, function (word) {return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;}));
},
    index: 1,replace: function (word) {return word + '  ';}
}]);
```

Comment: What is the regex engine you are using? Please keep only the relevant tag and remove all others. `\w` matches all Unicode letters and digits by default in .NET and Python 3.

Comment: I use this code on javascript

Comment: Ok, try `/(?:^|[^\wа-яё])([\wа-яё]{2,})$/i`

Comment: Thank's Wiktor Stribiżew! You code is working.

Comment: But "space" clearing from left when i select word.

Comment: What is the code behind the regex? You need to be able to access Group 1 value, the `[1]` item in the returned match object. If you can use regular code, `regex.exec(str)[1]`

Comment: I'm change my question please see full code

Comment: Acc. to the docs, the text you need to keep should be inside a capturing group. So, try `/((?:^|[^\wа-яё])[\wа-яё]{2,})$/i` if you need to keep the whole match. Not sure what will help here. Also, try `/(^|[^\wа-яё])([\wа-яё]{2,})$/i`  or also try to set `index: 1` or `2`.

Comment: John, I think my answer is now complete, please check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155602/discussion-between-john-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```js
$('.form-control').textcomplete([
{ 
    words: ["россия","сша","англия","германия","google","git","github","php","microsoft","jquery"], 
    match: /(^|[^\wа-яё])([\wа-яё]{2,})$/i,
    search: function (term, callback) 
    { 
        callback($.map(this.words, function (word) {return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;}));
    },
    index: 2, // THIS IS A DEFAULT VALUE
    replace: function (word) {return '$1' + word + ' ';}
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/0.2.2/jquery.textcomplete.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" rows=5 cols=50></textarea>
```

The pattern `(^|[^\wа-я])([\wа-я]{2,})$` works as follows:

- `(^|[^\wа-яё])` - Capturing group 1: start of string or any char other than a word and Russian letters
- `([\wа-яё]{2,})` - Capturing group 2: 2 or more word or Russian letters
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**:

- We need both capturing groups to be able to keep the non-word char or start of string before the match we need to modify
- To keep the char that can be matched and captured into Group 1 should be restored with the `$1` inside the `replace` (see [this source code](https://github.com/yuku-t/textcomplete/blob/master/src/search_result.js#L21) showing that all the literal `$n` backreferences are replaced with `match[n]`)
- Thus, we no longer need to replace with double spaces at the end, use `return '$1' + word + ' ';`
- We need to use `index: 2` since this value will be handled as the term
- To match all Russian letters, you need to add `ё` to the character classes since the `[а-я]` range does not include it
- Also, the `index` value is set to `2` by default, thus, you may remove `index: 2` from the code above.

Comment: It's very well working in my local site but in hosting not working. Here my site [link](https://mahorat.org)

Comment: @John I have opened the page in three browsers, IE, FF and Chrome, and it works the same as in my snippet above.

Comment: I opened page in older version google chrome. Now I opened page on Vivaldi and it's working. Thank's @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Can you change script to case insensitive?

Comment: @John But it **is** case insensitive, see the `/i` modifier.

Comment: When I write to textarea "Google" or "Россия" it's not working

Comment: @John: Ok, here are my findings. I doubt there is a way to make the module output the same case without some more profound change in the code. You may make it support the case insensitive search, but the replacements will be those hardcoded in the word list, see [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrt2xjpk/).

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew :) How I rewrite function to work in typing letters "ӯ,ҳ,қ,ҷ,ӣ,ғ". When I type words startin with this letters it's not work

Comment: @John Add them to the character classes.